# How to define properties to multiple CoffeeScript classes

Tags: coffeescript, prototypal-inheritance

I want to define multiple properties of different "classes"/prototypes when creating a new object.

```
class Animal
    constructor: (@name, @temperament, @diet) ->

    #methods that use those properties
    eat: (food) ->
        console.log "#{name} eats the #{food}."

class Bird extends Animal
    constructor: (@wingSpan) ->

    #methods relating only to birds

class Cat extends Animal
    constructor: (@tailLength) ->

    #methods relating only to cats

myCat = new Cat ("long", {"Mr. Whiskers", "Lazy", "Carnivore"})
```

I'm doing something wrong, though. Only the constructor for Cat seems to get any properties.

Also, is there a way to define them with key/value pairs?
Ideally, I'd write something like `myCat = new Cat (tailLength: "long", name: "Mr. Whiskers", temperament: "Lazy")`, so that I can define properties that aren't in order and it would fall back to a default if I failed to define a property like "diet".

My understanding is that prototype methods will bubble up, so if I call `myCat.eat 'cat food'`, the output should be `"Mr. Whiskers eats the cat food."` But... it can't be since the Animal class isn't getting the new Cat's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `{}` if you mean "an object".

```
class Animal
    constructor: ({@name, @temperament, @diet}) ->

    #methods that use those properties
    eat: (food) ->
        console.log "#{@name} eats the #{food}."

class Bird extends Animal
    constructor: ({@wingSpan}) ->
      super

    #methods relating only to birds

class Cat extends Animal
    constructor: ({@tailLength}) ->
      super

    #methods relating only to cats

myCat = new Cat(tailLength: "long", name: "Mr. Whiskers", temperament: "Lazy", diet: "Carnivore")
```

Comment: His question makes little to no sense, but this answer is so cool.

Comment: @michelpm Yeah, sorry. When you don't understand concepts, a lot of times its for lack of proper vocabulary to describe them with. And just general misunderstandings.

Comment: That's fine, I'm used to it -- glad I helped.

Comment: @user1737909 Thank you! 100% what I was trying to do. :)

Comment: @aminimalanimal I was wrong, your question is good. I had focused too much on the code.